# $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-p)^n$ when $X = 0$

Tags: limits, binomial-distribution

Could someone explain the following please:

[image]

Expanding $(1-p)^n$ using the maclaurin does not tend to zero as $n \to \infty$ Could someone enlighten me as to how this happens?

Comment: Well $0<p<1$ Since we are talking about probabilities, hence $0<1-p<1$ and hence $(1-p)^n$ gets smaller and smaller, and tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it this way, very clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r \in [0,1)$ the series $\sum r^{n}$ is a convergent geometric series. In particular $r^{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Take $r=1-p$.

Comment: Thanks for a fast response and a quick explanation!